# Laravel - Definir control de accesos mediante Homecontroller

Tags: laravel, vue.js

HomeController

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth:embajador','auth:experto']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

mi problema es que esta ciclando la información debido a que parece que no reconoce la autenticación. Hace un ciclo entre la ruta /login y /embajador.Y esto empezo a ocurrir cuando agregue la linea:

```
Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where('path','([A-z\d-\/_,]*)?');
```

Pero la necesito debido a que `vue` si hago refresh me manda a `404`

rutas:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where('path','([A-z\d-\/_,]*)?');
```

Si quito la linea

```
Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where('path','([A-z\d-\/_,]*)?');
```

Me funciona correctamente, pero no puedo usarlo con `vue` alguien sabe como puedo controlar los accesos o porque se esta ciclando las peticiones?